# Trying to get a list of files in a directory by created date using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a list of all files in a directory by write date:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DateTime LastCreatedDate = 
               Properties.Settings.Default["LastDateTime"].ToDateTime();

  string [] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")
                        .OrderBy(p => System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p))
                        .Where(p>=LastCreatedDate);
}
```

**Questions**

1. How do I properly do a WHERE clause to get only files greater than or equal to the date in my settings?
2. `string []` is not working for this one because it does not know how to do conversion. which data type should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but should work:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime LastCreatedDate = Properties.Settings.Default["LastDateTime"].ToDateTime();
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv").Select(p => new {Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p)})
        .OrderBy(x=>x.Date)
        .Where(x=>x.Date>=LastCreatedDate);

}
```

Comment: thanks so much! how would i parse each element in filepaths? foreach (var file in filepaths) ??

Comment: You can use foreach(var file in filePaths). Each element is anonymous type with properties Path and Date.

Comment: thank you!!!!! can yo uhelp with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386705/c-sharp-getting-last-element-in-linq-statement

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you're not using `DirectoryInfo` instead of `Directory` - this will save you having to parse the file paths back into `Files` to get the dates, or store the dates in a separate variable:

```
DateTime lastCreatedTime = new DateTime(2012, 01, 30, 05, 12, 00);

var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Pontos\completed\").GetFiles("*_*.csv")
            .Where(f => f.LastWriteTime >= lastCreatedTime)
            .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
            .Select(f => new {f.FullName});

foreach (var file in files) {
  Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")
         .Select(p => new { FileName = p, Modified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) })
         .Where(p => p.Modified > LastCreatedDate)
         .OrderBy(p => p.Modified);
```

Comment: Error 8 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'string[]' C:\Users\

Comment: Use `var x = ...`.  This will give you an enumerable result of the anonymous type created.

Comment: thank you!! can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386705/c-sharp-getting-last-element-in-linq-statement