# c# getting last element in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

```
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv").Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
        .Where(x => x.Date >= LastCreatedDate);
```

i would like to know the value of the most recent `x.Date`

from this linq statement how can i get the most recent date?

please note that i do not need the `filepath` rather i need the `DATE`

Comment: You can Order By descending, and add a .First() ad the end, or you can cast it to an array, and take the last element

Comment: @SamIam i believe this will give me the name but not the most recent created date right>?

Comment: It will give you whatever object you specified in your .Select() method

Comment: @SamIam you can also save yourself the cost of sorting the data by using `Max()`.

Answer (score 7):

```
var mostRecent = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")
    .Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) }) 
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date) 
    .Where(x => x.Date >= LastCreatedDate)
    .LastOrDefault();
```

or

```
var mostRecent = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")
    .Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) }) 
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date) 
    .Where(x => x.Date >= LastCreatedDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i believe this will give me the name but not the most recent created date right>?

Comment: @I__ - No, it gives you both name and date.  You access by mostRecent.Date

Answer (score 4):

Just reverse the order - also do the filtering before the ordering:

```
 var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv").Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) })
        .Where(x => x.Date >= LastCreatedDate)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead I would suggest you use `DirectoryInfo`'s `GetFiles()` instead which returns `FileInfo` instances so you don't have to grab the last write time manually:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Pontos\completed\");
var file =  di.GetFiles("*_*.csv")
              .Where(f=> f.LastWriteTimeUtc >= LastCreatedDate)
              .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTimeUtc)
              .FirstOrDefault();


if(file!=null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}, Last Write Time: {1}", file.FullName, 
                                                        file.LastWriteTimeUtc);
}
```

Comment: i believe this will give me the name but not the most recent created date right>?

Comment: No, it will return an instance of an anonymous type which has both Date and Path properties - but better to use `DirectoryInfo` - see update.

Answer (score 2):

F# has a handy `MaxBy()` function that I like to use; the C# implementation is trivial.  It allows you to avoid the cost of sorting the sequence.

See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759648/385844

usage:

```
var mostRecent = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")  
    .Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) })   
    .Where(x => x.Date >= LastCreatedDate)  
    .MaxBy(x => x.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method .Take(1);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")
            .Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p) })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
            .Where(x => x.Date >= LastCreatedDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

The changes to your statement are the sorting (OrderByDescending instead of OrderBy) to put the newest date "on top" and FirstOrDefault which will select the top, single item from the collection and should result in null if the collection is empty.

To get more file properties you could modify your anonymous object to include more properties, thusly:

```
        var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Pontos\completed\", "*_*.csv")
            .Select(p => new { Path = p, Date = File.GetLastWriteTime(p), CreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(p) })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
            .Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Now)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(filePath.Date);
        Console.WriteLine(filePath.Path);
        Console.WriteLine(filePath.CreatedDate);
```

Or more succinctly (no need for an anonymous object) you could do this:

```
        var filePath = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Pontos\completed\").GetFiles("*_*.csv")
            .Select(p => p)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime)
            .Where(x => x.CreationTime >= DateTime.Now)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(filePath.CreationTime);
        Console.WriteLine(filePath.FullName);
```

Comment: i believe this will give me the name but not the most recent created date right>?

Comment: @I__: You will get the path and lastWriteTime based on the anonymous object you created.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using LinqToObjects, if performance is a consideration, you should perhaps consider implementing a `MaxBy` type method, instead of using `OrderBy` combined with `FirstOrDefault`.

I'll find you an implementation. [no need... see @phoog's answer]